# How does CSS properties from figma files in 1920X1080 screen resolution work on different laptop screen resolution?

Tags: reactjs, sass, media-queries, figma, grid-system

I'm developing a website using reactJS, I've received the figma files in 1920X1080 screen resolution.If i'm trying to develop those screens in a laptop with lesser screen resolution, the screens are overflowing from the viewport. How do I fix this.

I tried using grids in the CSS but it did'nt help.

Comment: I assume that means you are using fixed sizes for everything, ie. `width: 300px;`?